# Getting Artifact missing error while Adding Onedrive Dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, onedrive, maven-dependency

I am getting an missing dependency error with this dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nuxeo.onedrive</groupId>
  <artifactId>onedrive-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked that the artifact *is* in maven repository (`mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nuxeo.onedrive/...`)

Comment: please add stack-trace of the mentioned error as this will make it easier to debug.

Comment: check whether this dependency is downloaded OR available in maven local repo